# Is it possible to customize certain words in localizable strings?

Tags: ios, swift, string, localization

I have a `localizable string` in US English that reads

`"message" = "The distance is 10 feet";`

Is it possible to customize the words `"10 feet"` for lets say British English so that it becomes "x meters" instead so when language is set to GB in the settings menu?

Or do I need to create a seperate localizable.string file for that? Have read that there may be some issues adding regional language support.

Comment: If the message is the entire sentence (which it is usually the best thing to do when we localize), yes, you can do it: you localize the entire sentence. If you translate part of string, (e.g. `10` and then `feet`), no, but this is also bad. On some language plural may need also other changes in the previous part of sentence. So: it should be ok, or you have localization problems

Comment: You might be able to find what you want with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter for your specific issue with distances. It should get rid of plural/single (which might be different across different languages), and/or the position of that string in the sentence. I would suggest to have: `"message" = "The distance is %@";`.

Answer (score 0):

in your Localizable.strings file you can set

```
"message" = "The distance is %d %@";
```

Then check if current iPhone language is Englis US or English UK and set value and unit according to that

```
var localizedText = NSLocalizedString("message", comment"")

localizedText = localizedText.replaceingOccurences(of: "%d", with : String(10/* set value */))

localizedText = localizedText.replaceingOccurences(of: "%@", with : "feet" /*set unit*/)
```

You can use string formatting also :

```
let localizedText = String(format: NSLocalizedString("message", comment""),value, unit )
```

Comment: Why use `replaceingOccurences` and not use `string(format:)` since they are already valid "placeholders".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. This is an example:

```
"message" = "The distance is %d feet";
let originMessage = NSLocalizedString("message", comment: "")
let yourCustomMessage = String(format: originMessage, yourNumber)
```

Comment: One foot, multiple feet, no? You don't handle that case. And the user asked, what if the user prefers meters over feet?